# Why is wlo1 not routing DNS response back to enp4s0?

Tags: 20.04, dns, iptables, connection-sharing

I'm sharing my wifi connection (wlo1) via ethernet (enp4s0) to another device.  The packet forwarding worked until the host device rebooted.

All routes and IP addresses are static, set up using NMCLI.

Network Configuration:

```
wlo1: connected to WLAN_JTC
        "Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6235"
        wifi (iwlwifi), 32:0A:48:9C:36:25, hw, mtu 1500
        ip4 default
        inet4 172.16.7.225/20
        route4 172.16.0.0/20
        route4 0.0.0.0/0

enp4s0: connected to enp4s0
        "Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411"
        ethernet (r8169), 9E:3B:65:41:8D:E9, hw, mtu 1500
        inet4 10.0.0.1/30
        route4 10.0.0.0/30
        route4 169.254.0.0/16

lo: unmanaged
        "lo"
        loopback (unknown), 00:00:00:00:00:00, sw, mtu 65536

DNS configuration:
        servers: 1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
        interface: wlo1

        servers: 1.1.1.1 8.8.8.8
        interface: enp4s0
```

IPTABLES:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Wed Jul 29 15:50:34 2020
*filter 
:INPUT DROP [557:29706] 
:FORWARD DROP [13801:2463326] 
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [447:43334]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22,80,443,8096,8920 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m multiport --sports 53,7359 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/30 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.0.0.0/30 -o wlo1 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --sports 22,80,443,8096,8920 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m multiport --dports 53,7359 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -j ACCEPT COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jul 29 15:50:34 2020
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Wed Jul 29 15:50:34 2020
*nat 
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [5695:386224] 
:INPUT ACCEPT [415:27457] 
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [335:27272] 
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [104:9627]
-A PREROUTING -d 10.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8096
-A PREROUTING -d 172.16.7.225/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8096
-A PREROUTING -d 10.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8920
-A PREROUTING -d 172.16.7.225/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8920
-A OUTPUT -d 10.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8096
-A OUTPUT -d 172.16.7.225/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8096
-A OUTPUT -d 10.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8920
-A OUTPUT -d 172.16.7.225/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8920
-A POSTROUTING -o wlo1 -j MASQUERADE COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jul 29 15:50:34 2020
```

ipv4 forwarding is enabled:

```
$ sudo sysctl -a | grep -e "net.ipv4.conf.*\.forwarding"
net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.enp4s0.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.lo.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.wlo1.forwarding = 1
```

TCPDUMP showing DNS request being forwarded to wlo1 but not back to enp4s0:

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked v1), capture size 262144 bytes
15:41:28.475263 IP 10.0.0.2.42949 > 1.1.1.1.53: 19935+ A? dns.msftncsi.com. (34)
15:41:28.475337 IP 172.16.7.225.42949 > 1.1.1.1.53: 19935+ A? dns.msftncsi.com. (34)
15:41:28.475366 IP 10.0.0.2.42949 > 8.8.4.4.53: 19935+ A? dns.msftncsi.com. (34)
15:41:28.475375 IP 172.16.7.225.42949 > 8.8.4.4.53: 19935+ A? dns.msftncsi.com. (34)
15:41:28.475382 IP 10.0.0.2.42949 > 8.8.8.8.53: 19935+ A? dns.msftncsi.com. (34)
15:41:28.475390 IP 172.16.7.225.42949 > 8.8.8.8.53: 19935+ A? dns.msftncsi.com. (34)
15:41:28.478556 IP 1.1.1.1.53 > 172.16.7.225.42949: 19935 1/0/0 A 131.107.255.255 (66)
15:41:28.526947 IP 8.8.4.4.53 > 172.16.7.225.42949: 19935 1/0/0 A 131.107.255.255 (50)
15:41:28.527450 IP 8.8.8.8.53 > 172.16.7.225.42949: 19935 1/0/0 A 131.107.255.255 (50)
15:41:29.227928 IP 10.0.0.2.43252 > 8.8.8.8.53: 2+ A? www.netgear.com. (33)
15:41:29.228014 IP 172.16.7.225.43252 > 8.8.8.8.53: 2+ A? www.netgear.com. (33)
15:41:29.307591 IP 8.8.8.8.53 > 172.16.7.225.43252: 2 5/0/0 CNAME d3jdtixm7cvu7y.cloudfront.net., A 13.225.78.114, A 13.225.78.98, A 13.225.78.100, A 13.225.78.113 (140)
15:41:33.809276 IP 10.0.0.2.39438 > 8.8.8.8.53: 57002+ A? fus01.ps4.update.playstation.net. (50)
15:41:33.809361 IP 172.16.7.225.39438 > 8.8.8.8.53: 57002+ A? fus01.ps4.update.playstation.net. (50)
15:41:33.889200 IP 8.8.8.8.53 > 172.16.7.225.39438: 57002 3/0/0 CNAME wild.ps4.update.playstation.net.edgekey.net., CNAME e7856.d.akamaiedge.net., A 23.50.185.215 (153)
15:41:34.246328 IP 10.0.0.2.52323 > 8.8.8.8.53: 2+ A? www.netgear.com. (33)
15:41:34.246408 IP 172.16.7.225.52323 > 8.8.8.8.53: 2+ A? www.netgear.com. (33)
15:41:34.309107 IP 8.8.8.8.53 > 172.16.7.225.52323: 2 5/0/0 CNAME d3jdtixm7cvu7y.cloudfront.net., A 13.225.78.113, A 13.225.78.98, A 13.225.78.114, A 13.225.78.100 (140)
15:41:34.372124 IP 10.0.0.2.10824 > 8.8.8.8.53: 6304+ A? www.google.com. (32)
15:41:34.372210 IP 172.16.7.225.10824 > 8.8.8.8.53: 6304+ A? www.google.com. (32)
15:41:34.423672 IP 8.8.8.8.53 > 172.16.7.225.10824: 6304 1/0/0 A 172.217.21.4 (48)
15:41:34.957237 IP 10.0.0.2.41139 > 8.8.8.8.53: 36090+ A? gmail.com. (27)
15:41:34.957323 IP 172.16.7.225.41139 > 8.8.8.8.53: 36090+ A? gmail.com. (27)
15:41:35.020244 IP 8.8.8.8.53 > 172.16.7.225.41139: 36090 1/0/0 A 172.217.21.5 (43)
15:41:35.386002 IP 10.0.0.2.10824 > 1.1.1.1.53: 6304+ A? www.google.com. (32)
15:41:35.386087 IP 172.16.7.225.10824 > 1.1.1.1.53: 6304+ A? www.google.com. (32)
15:41:35.386115 IP 10.0.0.2.10824 > 8.8.4.4.53: 6304+ A? www.google.com. (32)
15:41:35.386128 IP 172.16.7.225.10824 > 8.8.4.4.53: 6304+ A? www.google.com. (32)
15:41:35.386135 IP 10.0.0.2.10824 > 8.8.8.8.53: 6304+ A? www.google.com. (32)
15:41:35.386143 IP 172.16.7.225.10824 > 8.8.8.8.53: 6304+ A? www.google.com. (32)
30 packets captured
30 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was easier than I expected.  I simply added the following iptables rule to enable forwarding back to the appropriate subnet.

```
-A FORWARD -i wlo1 -d 10.0.0.0/30 -j ACCEPT
```

As shown below, the packet flow is working as expected:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -n -i 'any' port not 22 | grep -e ".*8\.8\.8\.8.*"
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked v1), capture size 262144 bytes
15:05:25.696116 IP 10.0.0.2.17916 > 8.8.8.8.53: 64416+ A? www.google.com. (32)
15:05:25.696165 IP 172.16.7.225.17916 > 8.8.8.8.53: 64416+ A? www.google.com. (32)
15:05:25.749704 IP 8.8.8.8.53 > 172.16.7.225.17916: 64416 1/0/0 A 172.217.171.228 (48)
15:05:25.749745 IP 8.8.8.8.53 > 10.0.0.2.17916: 64416 1/0/0 A 172.217.171.228 (48)
15:05:25.847597 IP 10.0.0.2.39339 > 8.8.8.8.53: 64074+ A? us-prof.np.community.playstation.net. (54)
15:05:25.847646 IP 172.16.7.225.39339 > 8.8.8.8.53: 64074+ A? us-prof.np.community.playstation.net. (54)
15:05:25.931348 IP 8.8.8.8.53 > 172.16.7.225.39339: 64074 4/0/0 CNAME 13673-wildcard.np.community.playstation.net.edgekey.net., CNAME 13673-wildcard.np.community.playstation.net.edgekey.net.globalredir.akadns.net., CNAME e13673.b.akamaiedge.net., A 2.17.24.173 (259)
15:05:25.931374 IP 8.8.8.8.53 > 10.0.0.2.39339: 64074 4/0/0 CNAME 13673-wildcard.np.community.playstation.net.edgekey.net., CNAME 13673-wildcard.np.community.playstation.net.edgekey.net.globalredir.akadns.net., CNAME e13673.b.akamaiedge.net., A 2.17.24.173 (259)
```